# How to properly specify Jacobian & Hessian functions of inequality constraints in Optim

Tags: optimization, julia, nonlinear-optimization, hessian-matrix

I’m trying to use the Optim package in Julia to optimize an objective function with 19 variables, and the following inequality constraints:

```
0 <= x[1]/3 - x[2] <= 1/3 
5 <= 1/x[3] + 1/x[4] <= 6
```

I’m trying to use either `IPNewton()` or `NewtonTrustRegion` , so I need to supply both a Jacobian and Hessian for the constraints. My question is: what is the correct way to write the Jacobian and Hessian functions?

I believe the constraint function would be

```
function con_c!(c,x)
   c[1] = x[1]/3 - x[2]          
   c[2] = 1/x[3] + 1/x[4]
   c
end
```

Would the Jacobian function be

```
function con_jacobian!(J,x)
   #first constraint:
   J[1,1] = 1/3
   J[1,2] = -1.0
  #second constraint:
   J[2,3] = -1/(x[3])^2
   J[2,4] = -1/(x[4])^2
   J
end
```

? (I assume all other indices of `J` are automatically set to zero?)

My main question: What would the Hessian function be? This is where I’m most confused. My understanding was that we take Hessians of scalar-valued functions. So do we have to enter *multiple* Hessians, one for each constraint function (2 in my case)?

I’ve looked at the multiple constraints example given here https://github.com/JuliaNLSolvers/ConstrainedOptim.jl , but I’m still confused. In the example, it looks like they are adding together two Hessian matrices…? Would greatly appreciate some help.

FD: I posted this question on Discourse two days ago but didn't receive a single response, which is why I'm posting it here.

Comment: Replied on Discourse: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/how-to-properly-specify-jacobian-hessian-functions-of-inequality-constraints-optim/53870